How to create a sidecar container in ArgoCD deployment yaml?
I am trying to create a sidecar container within ArgoCD itself. So far, I went with extraContainers field in an external values.yaml in order to configure ArgoCD.
extraContainers:
- name: artifactory-cache
     env:
       - name: NGINX_PORT
         value: "8080"
       - name: CACHE_TTL
         value: "20m"
       - name: ARTIFACTORY_HOST
         value: "$ARTIFACTORY_HOST"
     image: path/to/nginx/image
     imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
     resources:
       limits:
         cpu: 2
         memory: 2Gi
       requests:
         cpu: 200m
         memory: 200Mi
     volumeMounts:
       - name: artifactory-cache-data
         mountPath: /var/cache/nginx

Simply, I wanted to deploy an intermediate container which will be an nginx proxy cache between Argo and our artifactory. I could manage to cache the artifactory bits with this configuration but syncing apps fail because of a sidecar related error coming from ArgoCD.
The error coming from ArgoCD:
ComparisonError
Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = plugin sidecar failed. could not find plugin supporting the given repository

I think ArgoCD thinks our sidecar container is a plugin, where it should not be. Can you please explain me why ArgoCD fails with this configuration?
ArgoCD version: v2.12.4
I tried creating a sidecar for these; application-controller, repo-server, server, applicationset-controller, yet they all ended up in same result.

Why do you need this intermediate cache? And why as a side car container? I would have it as a standalone container outside of ArgoCD if I need to but I don't see the point if you've got an Artifactory, use it directly: it's its role. Also, what do you expect to cache? Helm files?

The aim is to reduce the cost of network communication because the artifactory is outside cloud network. The initial aim is to cache metadata of artifactory, which helm chart-versions exists. Then, caching artifacts can be considered.
